# Unstable smtp behaviour in python script

Tags: python, linux, sendmail

I have a python script sending email via sendmail. But it is unstable, some times it can send email, some times it doesn't.

In /var/log/syslog I receive following logs on unsuccessful and successful sendmail attempts respectively.

Unsuccessful mail delivery:

```
postfix/smtp[24974]: 484D83614DF: to=<someaddress@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=20, delays=0.01/0.02/20/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp.gmail.com type=A: Host not found, try again)
```

Successful mail delivery

```
postfix/smtp[57449]: 2DAFC361287: to=<someaddress@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[74.125.195.109]:587, delay=7.6, delays=0.01/0.06/5.8/1.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1488801313 t30sm26793865wra.52 - gsmtp)
```

On unsuccessful attempts I get **relay=none** and **Host or domain name not found...** I am using an Ubuntu guest vmware on Windows host. What can be possible reasons behind this unstable behaviour?

Comment: Your DNS service or your internet connection is not reliable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error points to a problem in your network not your code.